# Only secure origins are allowed in ionic 3

Tags: geolocation, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova geolocation plugin in my ionic 3 app. It is working on some android devices but not working on OnePlus A5010

I am getting the error "Only secure origins are allowed".

I have already SSL implemented in my app.

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';    

let locationOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true}; 

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationOptions).then((position) => {

 }).catch((error) => { console.log('Error getting location', error); });
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

My guess is that you are calling an API with an http:// instead of https://

Comment: I have already SSL implemented 
   import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 
   let locationOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationOptions).then((position) => {
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

Comment: Please include the code in your question body, not as a comment, where it can get lost and is unreadable.